# adding mathview library in android project via dependency

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me whether adding a dependency in build.gradle is and then syncing it is sufficient to use a library in android studio for a project.

Comment: yes, it is sufficient.

Comment: That means there is no need to download the .aar file and do further steps.

Comment: yes, while synchronizing, it means it is downloading important files to integrate that library in your app.